# Setting a list of tag files

Tags: vimrc, tags

Is there a way to set multiple default tag files, to be searched sequentially in my vimrc? My hope was that I would be able to have a local tags file that would be searched first and then, if nothing was found, it would move onto the next given tags file (and so on ideally, but at this point I'm mainly interested in the case of 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. See [`help 'tags'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27tags%27):

```
set tags+=./my_local_tags_name
set tags+=other_tags_file_name
```

The default is `"./tags,tags"`, which would do what you want if you can name your tags files in this way.

The tags option takes a comma-separated list of files to search for when using tags. But the usage of `+=` is preferred to manual comma addition.

Comment: Don't know how I overlooked that on the help page. Thank you! @D.BenKnoble

Comment: The default is "./tags;,tags", there is a ";", which marks upward search.